# How to trace the originated uri of an obtained $_GET object from a remote page?

Tags: php, url, get, uri

Thousands of ?queries are listed in hundreds of html pages. When one of these queries is clicked and passed to a specific page:-

```
<?php 
      $obtained= $_GET['query'];
```

How to trace the URI of where it came from and paste it here? :-

```
      file_get_contents(../folder_of_pages_contain_queries/originated_page.html);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) in your second page to figure out where the request came from.

If you want to paste the contents in the second page, you can try:

```
if (isset ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && ! empty ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
    $contents = file_get_contents ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

Here is an example:

file1.html:

```
Link 1: <a href="test.php?query=link1">link 1</a>
Link 2: <a href="test.php?query=link2">link 2</a>
Link 3: <a href="test.php?query=link3">link 3</a>
```

file2.html:

```
Link 1: <a href="test.php?query=link1">link 1</a>
Link 2: <a href="test.php?query=link2">link 2</a>
Link 3: <a href="test.php?query=link3">link 3</a>
```

test.php:

```
$query = $_GET['query'];
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Depending on your test cases:

1. If user clicks on `link 2` from `file1.html`, then the value of `$query` will be "link2", and `$referer` will be "file1.html".
2. If user clicks on `link 3` from `file2.html`, then the value of `$query` will be "link3", and `$referer` will be "file2.html".

Comment: How to relate the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] with the $obtained= $_GET['query'] so that it knows which http to retrieve?

Comment: I'm trying to guess what you mean by "how to relate `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` with `$_GET['query']`". Please see my edited answer and let me know if it makes sense and is close to what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you Sutandiono, your suggestion works well and the problem solved!